# What is the highest operational ceiling for an air-breathing jet engine?

Tags: jet-engine, altitude, high-altitude

An [air-breathing jet engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbreathing_jet_engine) can only operate at relatively low altitude, where the atmosphere is dense enough. However, some jet-powered aircraft can operate at an altitude higher than 20 Km (e.g., the SR-71). For really high altitude, aircraft are equipped with rocket engines (e.g., the X-15)

What is the highest operational altitude for any air-breathing jet-powered aircraft?

Comment: I think somewhere on Wikipedia has a page which lists the highest aircrafts by category: rocket engines / air breathing engines / blimps etc.

Comment: From what I found: [MiG-25 37,650 metres (123,520 ft)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikoyan-Gurevich_MiG-25#Aviation_records)

Comment: @kevin I did find a [page about altitude records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_altitude_record#Fixed-wing_aircraft) but none about operational ceiling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Scramjet engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scramjet), which is still technically an Air breathing engine, will provide the highest possible service ceiling.

Theoretically, they can operate at up to 250,000 ft (75 km). For comparison, "space" begins at around 330,000 ft (100 km).

More technical info about Scramjet engines can be found [here](http://upcommons.upc.edu/bitstream/handle/2099.1/20295/Technical%20Report.pdf).

Comment: You should had more references for further readings and to sustain your claim of theoretical ceiling for scramjet. E.g. a research paper from the nasa is quite more authoritative than a wikipedia link and provide more insight

Comment: @ManuH Maybe this will give you some more info: http://upcommons.upc.edu/bitstream/handle/2099.1/20295/Technical%20Report.pdf

Comment: @JimPP you really should edit the question. such a link is better fitted in the answer than in its comments.

Comment: @ManuH I will, thanks!

Comment: @Jimy: A bit too late, but I can't find the numbers in your linked document.

Comment: Where the atmosphere "ends" and space "begins" is a matter of definition. The atmosphere's sea level composition (78% _N2_ 21% _O2_ 1% _Ar_) ends at the turbo-/mesopause around 53 mi (85 km) altitude. Hydrogen and helium mostly prevail above 550 mi (880 km). The ozone layer is thickest around 15 mi (24 km). Water boils at body temperature at 12 mi (19 km).

Answer (score 3):

Below<sup>[1]</sup> shows the hypersonic *breathing* corridor. Without LOX or rocket assistance, the limit is around 140,000 feet (40 km) at around Mach 15.

In 2004 NASA's [X-43](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_X-43) achieved a record Mach 9.6 at 109,000 feet ([nasa.gov](https://www.nasa.gov/home/hqnews/2005/jun/HQ_05_156_X43A_Guinness.html)), which if you compare below, is a good match for the aforementioned corridor.

> [image]

---

1: Smart, Michael. "Scramjets." *The Aeronautical Journal* 111.1124 (2007): 605-619. ([PDF](https://www.sto.nato.int/publications/STO%20Educational%20Notes/RTO-EN-AVT-150/EN-AVT-150-09.pdf))